# focus() and focusout() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with focus() method in jQuery.
Here is my code...

```
  $('#input').focusout(function(){
    alert('message')
    $(this).focus();
  });
```

focusout() executed multiple times after calling focus() and because of the alert i can't do anything on the page!
Why?

Comment: it's an infinite loop you have here.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer:

```
$('#input').focusout(function(){
 alert('message');
},function(){

});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but wouldn't calling `alert()` on focus cause the input to lose focus, which would cause the same infinite loop?